# Issue with image orientation when capturing using camera2 api in android version 10

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-camera2, android-camera-intent

I have been updated my camera feature from Camera to camera2 api.

When i capture the image with front camera and display it in imageview. the orientation of the image is changed. Then i used this code to change the orientation of the image.

```
int jpegOrientation =
                (ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation) + characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION) + 270) % 360;
capturebuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, jpegOrientation);
```

Above code is working for android version(i.e version 5,9) which i have tested. When i run the same code in Android version 10 it does not work. Below is the image
[image]

please,any one can help me out for this issue

Comment: Did you find out why `capturebuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, jpegOrientation);` got ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the solution below :
https://medium.com/@kenodoggy/solving-image-rotation-on-android-using-camera2-api-7b3ed3518ab6

Comment: I have gone through this link but no use

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getJpegOrientation(CameraCharacteristics c, int deviceOrientation) {
     if (deviceOrientation == android.view.OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return 0;
     int sensorOrientation = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);

     // Round device orientation to a multiple of 90
     deviceOrientation = (deviceOrientation + 45) / 90 * 90;

     // Reverse device orientation for front-facing cameras
     boolean facingFront = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
     if (facingFront) deviceOrientation = -deviceOrientation;

     // Calculate desired JPEG orientation relative to camera orientation to make
     // the image upright relative to the device orientation
     int jpegOrientation = (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;

     return jpegOrientation;
 }
```

*to know more details follow this post: https://medium.com/@kenodoggy/solving-image-rotation-on-android-using-camera2-api-7b3ed3518ab6*

Comment: Hi saif, i have been using above method but still i find same issue in android version 10

Comment: Same here.. it does not matter *what* value is set for `JPEG_ORIENTATION`, the image comes out in the same (wrong) orientation *every time*